# Unable to resolve the source file for error in custom theme?

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, requirejs

I am working on magento version 2.1.3 and have a custom theme `shoppersbay`. For some js files it gives error like

> Unable to resolve the source file for
>   'frontend/Smartwave/shoppersbay/en_US/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/variations/paging/sizes.js'
>   0 /home4/shoppoz8/public_html/shoppersbay/vendor/magento/framework/App/StaticResource.php(97): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
>   1 /home4/shoppoz8/public_html/shoppersbay/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258):
>   Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch()
>   2 /home4/shoppoz8/public_html/shoppersbay/pub/static.php(13): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource))
>   3 {main}

I searched for the file `sizes.js` but i didn't find any in theme and in vendor directory. How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Because that file sizes.js is not belong to frontend scope. It belongs to adminhtml.

> magento/module-configurable-product/view/adminhtml/web/js/variations/paging/sizes.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/grid/paging/sizes'
], function (Sizes) {
    'use strict';

    return Sizes.extend({
        defaults: {
            excludedOptions: ['100', '200']
        },

        /**
         * @override
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.excludedOptions.forEach(function (excludedOption) {
                delete this.options[excludedOption];
            }, this);
            this.updateArray();

            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

Solution for your problem is delete any references to `sizes.js` in your custom theme. And asks the vendor to fix it, obviously :)

Comment: Yes `adminhtml` contains this js. But i can't find the reference to this file in the theme. Any help to find it. where i can search for it.

Comment: @NitinPawar Please use PhpStorm or whatever you like and search for 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/variations/paging/sizes.js' inside 'frontend/Smartwave/shopperbays'

Comment: I searched everywhere in theme and other modules but i can't found the reference for file. Also tried to remove file using `<remove src="file_name">` but it is not working.

Comment: @NitinPawar I'm so sorry, inside frontend/Smartwave/shopperbays may not contain this, it must be specified inside app/code/Smartwave